# Add Event on a dynamic Input Control in an ItemTemplate

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, event-handling, dynamic-controls

I have a list of Products displayed as input (checkbox) and I need to add an event every time a Product is selected, using ASP.NET in VB.NET.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left">                
        <tr>
            <td align="center" class="price" width = "200">
                <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="<%#Eval("ProductCode").ToString%>" runat="server"/>
            </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the code as an asp:checkbox and use the OnCheckedChanged property also remember to set AutoPostBack to true. You can not set the id to a dynamic value, but you can set a hidden field and use this

e.g

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cb1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="Checkbox_Click" AutoPostBack="true"/>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hd1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ProductCode") %>' />
```

Then in the code behind

```
Protected Sub Checkbox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim s As CheckBox = CType(sender, CheckBox)

    Dim hd As HiddenField = s.NamingContainer.FindControl("hd1")

    Dim ProductCode As String = hd.Value


End Sub
```